Get raw (escaped) attribute value from DOM element
How do get a raw, escaped attribute value from a DOM element so it can be used directly as a selector?
For example:


const selector = test.dataset.mydata;
console.log(selector); //it's not HTML friendly anymore

// selector is unescaped and can't be used directly:
const el = document.querySelector(`[myattr="${selector}"]`);
console.log(el);
<div id="test" data-mydata="{&quot;foo&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;blah&quot;}"></div>

<div myattr="{&quot;foo&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;blah&quot;}"></div>



Solution:
Use CSS.escape()


const selector = CSS.escape(test.dataset.mydata);
console.log(selector);

const el = document.querySelector(`[myattr="${selector}"]`);
console.log(el);
<div id="test" data-mydata="{&quot;foo&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;blah&quot;}"></div>

<div myattr="{&quot;foo&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;blah&quot;}"></div>




You want the opposite, the escaped/encoded value. Which you probably won't get, because how exactly a value was encoded in HTML is a detail lost once parsed by the HTML parser. You need to assume that any and all values may contain special characters, and escape/encode them appropriate before merging them into other strings.

const el = document.querySelector(\[myattr='${selector}']`);will work ... orconst el = document.querySelector(`[myattr="${selector.replaceAll('"', '\"')}"]`);`

@JaromandaX pretty sure it won't work, since " will not be &quot; anymore

I usually test things before I make such bold claims - i.e. I said "will work", meaning I already know it does

data-mydata="{&quot;foo&quot;... and data-mydata='{"foo"... are identical. The value of your attribute is {"foo"..., even if you didn't write it as such. &quot; means " in HTML.

You still would have to escape single quotes in the text.

if only CSS.encode() were a thing - but CSS.escape (never knew about it, so thank you for that) is the approach (it basically does what I did, except it handles ALL cases) - so const selector = CSS.escape(test.dataset.mydata);
